# how to get artistID from an array in rails and redirect using artistID as a param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am new to rails and am making a test app but am having a bit of trouble with getting a key/value from an array.

I want to search for an artist by artistName. Once a match has been found, I want to go to a bio page based on the artistID. The search by name works as expected but I am unable to then redirect using the artistID. Here is my code for artistID.

```
@artists = ["artists": {"artistName": "Nirvana", "artistID": "0001", "album": "Nevermind"}, {"artistName": "Pearl Jam", "artistID": "0201", "album": "Ten"}, {"artistName": "Alice In Chains", "artistID": "1192", "format": "Sap"}}]

@artists.each do |item|
 @artistID = item[:artistID]
end
```

The result of @artistID is always the last artistID in the array. I have also tried this

```
@artistID = Array.new
@artists.each do |item|
 @id = Hash.new
 @id = item[:artistID]
@artistID << @id
end
```

This then returns all artistID's. Can anyone help me get the correct artistID for the artist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That first line isn't a valid array, also you're not doing any comparison's to find the ID.  In the first one you're assigning the `@artistID` variable to every artistID, which in the end leaves you with only the last one.  The other example you're copying all of the IDs into an array.  Take a look at this:

```
artists = [
  {"artistName": "Nirvana", "artistID": "0001", "album": "Nevermind"},
  {"artistName": "Pearl Jam", "artistID": "0201", "album": "Ten"},
  {"artistName": "Alice In Chains", "artistID": "1192", "format": "Sap"}
]

found_artist = artists.find do |artist|
  artist[:artistName] == "Nirvana"
end

artistID = found_artist[:artistID]
puts artistID
```

This prints "0001" for me.